# Mann-Whitney U test for 3 samples in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've been struggling with how to analyse my data. I have three sets of non-parametric, unpaired data where n~100. Let's call them WT, KO and Con. I want to know if:

1. WT differs from KO
2. WT differs from Con
3. KO differs from Con

I have completed this in graphpad using "Dunn's multiple comparisons" but have been told using Mann-Whitney in R is a better for publication purposes. How can I determine this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a Kruskal-Wallis omnibus test with a Dunn test post-hoc.  For Dunn test, there's the dunnTest function in the FSA package.  I don't know if theoretically the omnibus K-W test is required or not before the Dunn test.

I can't imagine Dunn test would be less desirable for publication than pairwise Mann-Whitney.